# Eclipse scout 6.1: how to create simple decimal column in the table

Tags: eclipse-scout

After I add decimal column to the table, extended from AbstractDecimalColumn, there is no intuitive way to figure out how should method "createDefaultEditor" look like. 
Any direction from anybody maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractDecimalColumn` is not intended to be subclassed directly, it is more like a container for common code. You should always subclass either `AbstractIntegerColumn`, `AbstractBigDecimalColumn`, `AbstractLongColumn`, `AbstractBigIntegerColumn`

*(this should probably be mentioned that in the JavaDoc)*